# What is meant by "Graph" in Graph API for Facebook

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

As the title says: What does "Graph" mean in this context? And why is it named "Graph"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graph is used here in mathematical context. The Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29) could be helpful. Copying from the documentation:

> The Graph API presents a simple, consistent view of the Facebook
>   social graph, uniformly representing objects in the graph (e.g.,
>   people, photos, events, and pages) and the connections between them
>   (e.g., friend relationships, shared content, and photo tags).

Comment: kgiannakakis: So the name "graph" is used because it means this: "... a set of objects where some pairs of the objects are connected by links"?

Comment: I doubt that the facebook graph strictly conforms to the definition of a mathematical graph, but this is where the name came from. See the quoted text in my edited answer.

Comment: According to the text you quoted, they are real graphs, multi partite graphs to be precise.

Answer (score 2):

`Graph` in general is a mathematical term of a SET of nodes.

This is my own definition:

A `set` of `nodes` is a `graph` if there exists some notion of `edge` between nodes.

A `tree` is a `graph`

In [facebook](http://www.facebook.com), nodes could be a facebook user, a facebook page, a place, a group, or any other entity.

An edge is simply a relation between nodes.

For example:

1. A facebook user can be **a friend of** another facebook user.
2. A facebook user can **belong to** a group

Answer (score 1):

As @kgiannakakis explained a graph is a mathematical structure. Bascially like a tree but without a single root. (trees are graphs).

In Facebook, I guess nodes are "friends" and edges are "their relations".

Regards,
 Stéphane